# How can I achieve the following in oracle without creating a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

data set:

```
employee_id   phone_number
 1              123
 2              456
 3              789
```

result:

```
employee_id   phone_number
 1              123456
 2              456789
 3              789...
```

Comment: Please explain what the logic is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to concatenate the number from the next row, where `next` is defined by the `employee_id`:

```
select employee_id,
       (phone_number || lead(phone_number) over (order by employee_id) )
from table t;
```